# Turing Machine that computes maximum steps of halting machines

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

Suppose that $TM_{halting}$ is the set of machines that halt.

Given a number of states $m$ and a length $n$ of the input, let $f(m,n)$ be the maximum number of steps a machine with $m$ states in $TM_{halting}$ can take on an input of length $n$.

Is the function $f(m,n)$ computable?

Comment: You're talking about [busy beaver numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver). No, busy beaver numbers are not computable in general. We know some of the smaller ones, though!

Comment: This is a problem statement, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or about specific steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: I think the answers given perfectly answer my question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: If you could compute $f(m,n)$, then given a Turing machine $M$ with $m$ states and an input $x$ of length $n$, the Turing machine will either stop within $f(m,n)$ steps or never halt.

This argument actually shows that it is impossible to compute any *upper bound* on $f(m,n)$. In other words, $f(m,n)$ grows faster than any computable function.

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate a Turing machine for any fixed number of states to see whether it will halt.  If you could compute $f(m,n)$, you could solve the halting problem by simulating for $f(m,n)$ steps, then returning whether the test machine has halted yet or not.